# Third argument when creating model in MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Last few days I spent learning MongoDB and MongooseJS, and the best technique that works for me is reading code, lots of code. Today I've stumbled upon on two interesting things that are not covered by any documentation, or maybe they are and I just can't find the right section.

First thing I want to ask about is that `ref` property - what is it for? (I know it is offtopic, but when I set `index` property like in example below, will it help in searching Tags by User?)

```
var TagSchema = new Schema({
...
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        index: true
    },
...
});
```

Second (or third) thing is - what is doing that last argument?

```
mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema, 'tags');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're both in the documentation:

`ref` is part of Mongoose's support for reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

The third parameter to [`mongoose.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) is an explicit collection name.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's weird that I couldn't find, I am not as lazy as it seems, google'ing, Ctrl+F and analyzing code on Github didn't worked this time.

Comment: awesome! i've been confused over this for a couple of days. thank you for the answer!