# What is third parameter in mongoose.model? What is use of it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

`const db = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user')`

What is use of that third parameter?
Where can we use that parameter. What is use of that parameter. Any practical example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Third argument when creating model in MongooseJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390448/third-argument-when-creating-model-in-mongoosejs)

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is an explicit collection name.

Once I faced this use case , we had client and he want to have a prefix for each collection name when it get created in db ,something like "apple_users" , in that case it was useful

Comment: Yeah, I know that. but what is the exact use of that parameter? any practical example